# Mapping a property to a request header in RestKit 0.20-rc1

Tags: mapping, restkit

I am using RestKit 0.20-rc1 and I am under the impression that in order to set a header value for a request I need to configure a mapping using the @metadata expression. Here is what I have:

```
RKObjectMapping* mapping = [RKObjectMapping requestMapping];
[mapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
    @"etag": @"@metadata.HTTP.request.headers.If-Match"}
];

RKRequestDescriptor* desc = [RKRequestDescriptor requestDescriptorWithMapping:mapping
                                objectClass:[MyObject class] rootKeyPath:nil];
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] addRequestDescriptor: desc];
```

Now what I expect this to do is to set the value in the etag property in MyObject into the If-Match request header. Does this seem right or am I going about this the wrong way? Should I be setting the header directly in the request somehow? If so, how would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0):

To set a header value for a request, you can set the header of the object manager by setting the HTTPClient like you need it.

`[[RKObjectManager sharedManager].HTTPClient setDefaultHeader:@"yourHeaderField" value:@"yourValue"];`